# What is the difference between "anydata" and "any" types in Ballerina?

Tags: types, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I'm working with Ballerina and came across two types, `anydata` and `any`, which both seem to be used for handling dynamic types.
And I want to understand the nuances between them and their implications for type-safety and flexibility in my Ballerina programs.

Answer (score 3):

In Ballerina, the `anydata` and `any` types are both used to work with values of unknown or dynamic types. However, they serve different purposes and have distinct characteristics:

**anydata:**

- The `anydata` type is specifically designed for working with plain-data values. Therefore its defined as a union of the following Ballerina types.

  `() | boolean | int | float | decimal | string | xml | regexp:RegExp | anydata[] | map<anydata> | table<map<anydata>>`
- When you use `anydata`, you are essentially saying that the value you're working with is a data value, and you want type safety assurances for data operations.
- You can use pattern matching and type guards to safely extract and work with the underlying data of an `anydata` value.

**any:**

- The any type, on the other hand, is more permissive. It can hold values of any type including not just data values, but also behavioural values like Ballerina classes/objects, streams, etc, **only excluding errors**.
- When you use `any`, you are indicating that the value can be anything, and you may need additional type checks and runtime checks to determine its actual type and work with it safely.
- `any` provides more flexibility but sacrifices some level of type safety compared to anydata.

**Use Cases:**

- Use `anydata` when you specifically need to work with data values of unknown types, while making sure that the values are always safe for data operations. For example, when you are processing data from external sources like `JSON` or `XML` and need to ensure data integrity.
- Use `any` when you need to work with values of any kind, including the behavioural values. This is useful in cases where you want to pass around or manipulate arbitrary values, without being concerned about their specific types.